# Removing dataframe rows using a list of ints

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe. It contains `df['article_id']`. I'm using `to_sql` function with `sqlalchemy` to insert into my database. However, sometimes I have duplicate records that I want to remove before inserting.

This is my list:

```
usedIDs = []
select_st = select([article_table])
res = conn.execute(select_st)
for _row in res:
    clean = int(_row[1])
    usedIDs.append(clean)

usedIDs
```

With output:

```
[1202623831,
 1747352473,
 1748645480,
 1759957596,
 1811054956,
 1812183879,
 1816974229,
 2450784233,
 2579244390,
 2580336884]
```

What i've tried:

```
df[~df.isin(usedIDs)]
df.drop(usedIDs, axis=0)
```

And this does not work.
However when I hardcode it like below, it does work.

```
df = df[~df.article_id.isin(['1202623831','1747352473'])]
```

Error is either `unhashable` or `KeyError: not found in axis`.

How can I drop the rows from my dataframe where `df['article_id']` is in `usedIDs` list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just using "isin" will suffice like this on a sample data:

```
df
    one date
0   1   2019-05-10 06:00:16
1   2   2019-05-10 06:30:21
2   3   2019-05-10 07:00:03
3   4   2019-05-10 06:32:43
4   5   2019-05-10 07:33:31
5   6   2019-05-10 07:37:39:09
6   7   2019-05-10 07:49:01
7   8   2019-05-10 08:52:05
8   9   2019-05-10 08:29:44:10

df = df[~df.one.isin([1,2])]

df
    one date
2   3   2019-05-10 07:00:03
3   4   2019-05-10 06:32:43
4   5   2019-05-10 07:33:31
5   6   2019-05-10 07:37:39:09
6   7   2019-05-10 07:49:01
7   8   2019-05-10 08:52:05
8   9   2019-05-10 08:29:44:10
```

This works because you have changed the datatype from int to string

```
df = df[~df.article_id.isin(['1202623831','1747352473'])]
```

Try converting userIDs to strings like this:

```
userIDs = [str(userid) for userid in userIDs]
```

Comment: Tthat's the weird thing. This: df = df[~df.article_id.isin(['1202623831','1747352473'])] works.
But this: df = df[~df.article_id.isin(usedIDs)] doesn't.

Comment: @SomeName, check if usedIDs is not empty and also check if the type is same or not, userIDs may be string type

Comment: Thanks a ton! It was an object and I forgot my inplace=True on the convert.